# How to return to the UITableView page from the detail view page iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a main page set as a UITableView.  I have it set so that you can click on a row, then go to a detail page where there is a UIButton (a save button) which I would like to make the app return to the original page.  I know that it automatically sets a left bar button item as a return button, but I need to use a UIButton on the main part of the view.  Here is the code used to initialize the detail view.

```
addInputViewController *addV = [[addInputViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"addInputViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    addV.selectedCountry = selectedCountry;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:addV animated:YES];
    [addV release];
    addV = nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

Call

```
 [self.navigationController popViewController animated:YES];
```